# Bootstrap Popover Inside Popover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using twitter bootstrap to share my post on social media, i have made a link whose popover with some buttons content, but further when i click on buttons in popover, their popover function does not work.

```
<div class="well text-center">
<button id="but1" title='Popover' class="btn btn-success" rel='popover' data-placement="bottom" data-toggle='popover2'>Share</button>
</div>

<div class='container hide' id='cont'>
     <a onclick="Facebook()"
        class="btn btn-default">
        Facebook 
        </a>
         <a onclick="twitter()"
        class="btn btn-default">
        Twitter 
        </a>
         <a class="btn btn-default"
        data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-title="Login" data-container="body"
        type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login">
        Email 
        </a>
</div>

<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
      <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" maxlength="5">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="EmailToSomeOne();">Send</button>                                  
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

and the js

```
$('#but1').popover({
    html: true,
    content: $('#cont').html()
});


$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
    html: true, 
    content: function() {
          return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
});

function Facebook(){
    alert('share on facebook');
}
function twitter(){
    alert('share on twitter');
}

function EmailToSomeOne(){
 alert('Email to send');   
}
```

for more clearing i have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Taqi_Shah/haor6t2f/1/) also.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply bind the buttons with an id like

```
<a id="Facebook"class="btn btn-default">Facebook </a>
```

and access it using

```
$("#Facebook").on('click',function(){
    alert('share on facebook');
})
```

EDIT:
You cannot have nested popover in bootstrap.However you can use the below two approaches
1)You can change the html  inside the popover and display your email form

```
$('.popover-content').html($('#emailform').html())
```

Please refer to the fiddle attached for this appproach

https://jsfiddle.net/mohit181191/mxstLfnf/

2)You can open a modal on popover button click.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#facebook"
    class="btn btn-default">
```

Please refer to the below fiddle for this approach

http://jsfiddle.net/mohit181191/o35zqy7w/

Comment: nested pop is on email button

Comment: Thanks for working out, but i don't need popup model, I have handle it, since nested popover not supported, so it make two popover be separating social media and share and email to friend share.

Comment: Did you check the 1st apprach of replacing the html?

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine. Its just a jsFiddle setting issue.

In your fiddle select **no wrap (head)** in the dropdown on the left, click Run and it will work.

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/haor6t2f/4/)

When onLoad is selected your functions are defined within the closure of the $(document).ready(function() {}); only. Thats the reason it shows the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Facebook is not defined` (see the console)

BTW, here's an equivalent example on plunkr[enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/k6T1L9aSTOrXTuqflRUK?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap not support the Nested popover 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
$('body').on('click',".btn-default", function(){
   alert('share on facebook');
});
```

**.btn-default**  change this to your button default id